# Using React Hooks, using "useState" and "useEffect", is there a way to render a state waiting till the state has a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

**What am I trying to do?**

Render `characterInfo` via React Hooks onto the front-end.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

The front-end component rendering the info:

```
export default function ReactComponent() {
  const [characterInfo, setCharacterInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("/character/read");
    socket.on("/character/read", function (data) {
      if (data.status === "SUCCESS") {
        setCharacterInfo(data)
      }
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off("/character/read");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {characterInfo.models[0].name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The back-end `.json` info as "data" and also what is saved onto `characterInfo` by `setCharacterInfo`:

```
{
  status: "SUCCESS"
  models: [
    { 
      name: "AC",
      element: "Air",
    }
    {
      name: "Irene",
      element: "Fire",
    }
  ]
}
```

(so in this case to access "AC", it would be `characterInfo.models[0].name`)

**What do I expect the result to be?**

I expect simply `AC` to be rendered.

**What is the actual result?**

I would get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

**What I think the problem could be?**

I think it has to deal with asynchronous balancing, especially with the `useEffect()`. I think the front-end tries to render before `setCharacterInfo` decides to even set anything.

Comment: You need to loop through your results.   With something like ‘map’ over on rendering it

Comment: Also, your setting data as part of your state, when your state is set to characterInfo

Comment: For the first comment, if you're saying `{characterInfo.models.map((model) => (<div>{model.name}</div>))}`, the error I would receive is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'.`

For the second comment, yes I'm putting "data" into `setCharacterInfo` as a state, then the "data" should be me `characterInfo` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the front-end tries to render before setCharacterInfo decides to even set anything.

That's correct, your component renders once with the default `useState` value before the function in `useEffect` is run. Here's a diagram of the order of execution when a component mounts, updates, and unmounts (note `render` happens before `useEffect`):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/donavon/hook-flow/master/hook-flow.png

You'll need to check to see if `characterInfo.models` exists (and to be safe, make sure it has a length) before accessing `name`.

```
  return (
    <div>
      {
        characterInfo.models &&
        characterInfo.models.length &&
        characterInfo.models[0].name
      }
    </div>
  )
```

Or, if you're using optional chaining:

```
  return (
    <div>
      {characterInfo?.models[0]?.name}
    </div>
  )
```

One other note - you're setting the initial value of `characterInfo` to an empty array. If you make it an empty object, it will be clearer that you're expecting `data` to be an object, not an array.

```
const [characterInfo, setCharacterInfo] = useState({});
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and front-end wasn't rendering anything. I did a `console.log` for each of the values and this is what followed: `[{...}], undefined, "AC"`. Now when I tried just simply `{characterInfo.models && characterInfo.models[0].name}` it worked!

I tried the second solution and it led to the same problem of `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

I went ahead and did your note which I think is helpful to utilize.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your return statement to only render name if/when it exists

```
return (
    <div>
      {characterInfo.length && characterInfo.models[0].name}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: The solution didn't work for me, I went in deeper to see what values were being shown via a button that `console.log(characterInfo.length)` and `console.log(characterInfo.models[0].name)`, the first would show `undefined` and the second would show `"AC"`. Thank you for trying!